# MISRA Violation 12.5 when using && and || in if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean-logic, misra

I'm working on a project where we are appling MISRA 2004.

On most of the violations I got the reason, but one I don't understand:

Its in the if-statement with `&&` and `||` operations.

Example:

```
uint8 getValue()
{
   // Some algorithm, simplified with return 1
   uint8 someValue = 1u;
   return someValue;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint8 currentState = 0u;
    uint8 var_a = getValue();
    uint8 var_b = getValue();
    uint8 var_c = getValue();
    uint8 var_d = getValue();

    const uint8 const_a = 1u;
    const uint8 const_b = 2u;
    const uint8 const_c1 = 3u;
    const uint8 const_c2 = 30u;
    const uint8 const_d = 4u;

    if ((var_a == const_a) && (var_b == const_b) && ((var_c == const_c1) || (var_c == const_c2)) && (var_d == const_d))
    {
        currentState = 1;
    } else 
    {
        currentState = 2;
    }
}
```

This gives me twice the MISRA violation to rule 12.5 non-primary expression used with logical operator. Both are in the line with the IF-Statement

I don't see a problem with this if-statement, despite its a bit long.

Does anybody know, whats wrong here and how to solve that violation?

Edit:
I adjusted the example a bit.
I also noticed, that I get only one error if I simplify the if statement to:

```
if ((var_a == const_a) && ((var_c == const_c1) || (var_c == const_c2)) && (var_d == const_d))
```

And no violation if its changed to:

```
if ((var_a == const_a) && ((var_c == const_c1) || (var_c == const_c2)))
```

Comment: What __exactly__ are `var_X` and `const_X` in your case?

Comment: I wonder which of these is considered "non-primary". My guess is the two or'ed expressions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt An operand which is surrounded by parenthesis is always a primary expression, as per C17 6.5.1.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: They are both uint8

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I got two error in this line, both 12.5 non primary expression. I have some other if statements, they are all fine, just the one with || have problmens

Comment: If you're using **not** somewhere, you'd be non-compliant: `if (x && !y); // Noncompliant`

Comment: I'd then second Lundin's answer, that it's a false positive. However, the above is clearly not your actual code (I hope), so I wonder if you have tried to extract a [mcve] from your code?

Comment: @SimonGarfunkel Well then I believe you might have multiple violations of rule 10.1, but that doesn't explain the warning you are getting.

Comment: @Lundin, no I use this if-statement two times like in the example, and I have four misra violations 12.5, for each statement two.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, its a state machine, which transitions from one state into another, depending on the received values. So I actually have this exact if-statement. The only difference is, the namine of the variables and constants.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited the example to a minimal reproducable example. Sorry for the lazy previous example.

Comment: @SimonGarfunkel: Did you confirm the violation message occurs with the minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes i get two MISRA 12.5 violations in the line with the if statement, if I check the MISRA 2004 on the provided example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a false positive by your static analyser. Your code is compliant.

The rationale for MISRA C:2004 12.5 (and the equivalent rules in the 2012 version) is to avoid situations where operator precedence might not be obvious. Overall MISRA insists that sub-expressions involving binary operators ("complex expressions") should always have parenthesis.

In case of the boolean `&&` and `||` operators specifically, the rule 12.5 allows chaining multiple of them in the same expression, but not mixing `&&` and `||` in the same expression without parenthesis, since they have different precedence.

Had you written `&& (var_c == const_c1) || (var_c == const_c2) &&` then the code would be non-conforming. You didn't however, and you did also put parenthesis around the inner sub-expressions.